# Drug abuse and hair loss

Tags: hairloss, recreational-drugs

I've googled through internet but couldn't find straight answers. Are some recreational drugs known to cause hair loss?

Comment: Although this question needs editing. But there is a connection between drug abuse  ,hair loss and weight loss.

Answer (score 1):

Some [amphetamines can cause hair loss](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2805578/). The mechanism how this happens does not appear to be known.

Also some anabolic steroids (AAS) can cause it, presumably through [conversion to DHT](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4174066/). The situation with AAS is more complicated, as they can also [cause the opposite (hirsutism)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16827963). The effect of AAS depends on the area, i.e. whether the hair is [androgenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_hair) or not.

Comment: don't forget trichotillomania!

Comment: @faustus How does that relate to drug-induced hair loss ?

Comment: Psychostimulants can induce hair loss behaviourally i.e being high and pulling out one's hair.